# Is it possible to show all certificates of a node (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, certificate, mmc

Is it possible to show also local Computer Certificates as non-Administrator?
Over mmc.exe it's not possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer certificates are kept in Registry in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My`, which you must have read/execute permissions on.

At least on Windows XP, members of the "Users" group have enough access to read the `Certificates` subkey, meaning you just need to add the *Certificates - Local Machine* snap-in to MMC. Since MMC doesn't want you to do that, create a MMC console on another machine. ([Here's the one I use.](http://ompldr.org/vOTZkZQ/syscertmgr.msc) If MMC 3.0 consoles are incompatible with Windows 7, you'll have to create one on your own PC, then carry it over.)